# Python and spreadsheet: given the user input, expand the list of results using regex

Tags: python, google-sheets

I'm working with Python on a movie database on google sheets. I want to build a query searching a list of names and surnames on three columns. I ask the users to enter a name and the output will be the corresponding rows and some columns. I would like the user to enter just a name or a surname or even just a few letters, case insensitive. I would like my results to match "foreign characters " like ü ø å ... even if the user types the most similar char. Input "uber", output "über" Thank you!

My approach is to create a pattern and match whatever is before and after my input. For instance "russel" will match Jay Russell, Chuck Russell.. and "cuaron" match Alfonso Cuarón.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv(gsheet_url) #df is the whole spreadsheet

def get_actor():
    request_actor = input("Enter an actor: ")
    request_actor = request_actor.lower().title()
    if request_actor in df.values:
        mask1 = df['Actor1'].str.contains(request_actor)
        mask2 = df['Actor2'].str.contains(request_actor)
        mask3 = df['Actor3'].str.contains(request_actor)
        actor_data = df.loc[mask1 | mask2 | mask3, ['Title', 'Year', 'Genres', 'Director']]
        print('All the movies of the actor you were looking for\n', actor_data, '\n')
        print('Do you want to do a new search or find data?')
        welcome()

    else:
        print('The actor is not present in the database')
        print('Do you want to do a new search or find data?')
        welcome()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I paresed the dataframe twice. After the first iteration, if the input was not found among the df values, I applied the `.normalize()`, `.encode()`, `.decode()` methods to the df.

```
import pandas as pd
def get_actor():
    request_actor = input("Type an actor: ")
    request_actor = request_actor.lower().title().strip()
    search = False
    df_copy = df.copy(deep=True)
    for value in df_copy[['Actor1', 'Actor2', 'Actor3']].values:
        for item in value:
            if request_actor in str(item):
                search = True

    if not search:
        df_copy['Actor1'] = (
            df_copy['Actor1'].str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode(
                'ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8'))
        df_copy['Actor2'] = (
            df_copy['Actor2'].str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode(
                'ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8'))
        df_copy['Actor3'] = (
            df_copy['Actor3'].str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode(
                'ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8'))
        for value in df_copy[['Actor1', 'Actor2', 'Actor3']].values:
            for item in value:
                if request_actor in str(item):
                    search = True

    if search:
        mask1 = df_copy['Actor1'].str.contains(request_actor)
        mask2 = df_copy['Actor2'].str.contains(request_actor)
        mask3 = df_copy['Actor3'].str.contains(request_actor)
        actor_data = df_copy.loc[mask1 | mask2 | mask3, [
            'Title', 'Genres', 'Director', 'Actor1', 'Actor2', 'Actor3',
            'IMDB Score']]
        print(actor_data)
    else:
        print("This actor was not present in the database")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Most importantly I would like to my results to "foreign carachters"
> like ü ø å ... regardles of what the users types (they might not have
> those char immediately available or not sure about the spelling.

Regarding diacritics you might use `unicodedata` (it is part of standard library) to remove them as follows

```
import unicodedata
def remove_diacritics(text):
    return ''.join(i for i in unicodedata.normalize('NFD',text) if i.isascii())
print(remove_diacritics("Cuarón"))
```

output

```
Cuaron
```

Comment: Actually I'd like to work the other way round, my bad if I wasn't clear enough. Input "Cuaron" match "Cuarón".